# R: DocumentTermMatrix Wrong Frequencies after mgsub

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

I have a DocumentTermMatrix and I´d like to replace specific terms in this document and to create a frequency table.

The starting point is the original document as follows:

```
library(tm)
library(qdap)

    df1 <- data.frame(word =c("test", "test", "teste", "hey", "heyyy", "hi"))
    tdm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(as.character(df1$word))
```

When I create a frequency table of the original document I get the correct results:

```
freq0 <- as.matrix(sort(colSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing=TRUE))
freq0
```

So far so good. However, if replace some terms in the document then the new frequency table gets wrong results:

```
    tdm$dimnames$Terms <- mgsub(c("teste", "heyyy"), c("test", "hey"), as.character(tdm$dimnames$Terms), fixed=T, trim=T)
    freq1 <- as.matrix(sort(colSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing=TRUE))
    freq1
```

Obviously or perhaps some indexing in the document is wrong because even same terms are not regarded as identical while counting the terms.

This outcome should be the ideal case:

```
df2 <- data.frame(word =c("test", "test", "test", "hey", "hey", "hi"))
tdm2 <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(as.character(df2$word))
tdm2$dimnames$Terms <- mgsub(c("teste", "heyyy"), c("test", "hey"), as.character(tdm2$dimnames$Terms), fixed=T, trim=T)
freq2 <- as.matrix(sort(colSums(as.matrix(tdm2)), decreasing=TRUE))
freq2
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Thx in advance

Comment: I get error with `as.DocumentTermMatrix(as.character(df1$word))#Error in .TermDocumentMatrix(t(x), weighting) : 
  argument "weighting" is missing, with no default`

Comment: library(qdap) had wrong position in the code. Now it should be reproducible

Comment: I am not sure why the `colSums` is used as `as.matrix(tdm)` is 1 row/5 column.  You can try `m1 <- as.matrix(tdm); tapply(m1, dimnames(m1)[[2]], FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look at the structure of `as.matrix(tdm)`

```
str(as.matrix(tdm))
#num [1, 1:5] 1 1 1 2 1
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ Docs : chr "all"
# ..$ Terms: chr [1:5] "hey" "heyyy" "hi" "test" ...
```

which is one row, 5 column matrix, so `colSums` is basically not doing anything.

```
xtabs(as.vector(tdm)~tdm$dimnames$Terms)
#tdm$dimnames$Terms
#  hey heyyy    hi  test teste 
#   1     1     1     2     1
```

and after replacing using `mgsub`

```
xtabs(as.vector(tdm)~tdm$dimnames$Terms)
#tdm$dimnames$Terms
# hey   hi test 
#  2    1    3
```

The `xtabs` does the `sum` of the `vector`.  This can also be done with `tapply`

```
 tapply(as.vector(tdm), tdm$dimnames$Terms, FUN = sum)
```

---

If the number of rows are greater than 1, we can use `colSums`

```
 tapply(colSums(as.matrix(tdm)),  tdm$dimnames$Terms, FUN = sum)
 # hey   hi test 
 #  4    2    6
```

NOTE: The above output is after we made the changes with `mgsub`

Comment: thx, this is great answer! But what is the case if I have two documents and therefore two rows and 5 columns, then the function above does not work:
`df1 <- data.frame(word =c("test", "test", "teste", "hey", "heyyy", "hi"))
df1.1 <- data.frame(word =c("teste", "teste", "teste", "hey", "heyyy", "hi"))
tdm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(as.character(df1$word))
tdm2 <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(as.character(df1.1$word))
tdm <- c(tdm, tdm2)`

Comment: @OAM In that case you can use `colSums` and use that in the lhs of '~` .

Comment: @OAM i.e. `tapply(colSums(as.matrix(tdm)),  tdm$dimnames$Terms, FUN = sum)`

Comment: great and perfect!